# ¿Por que cuando queremos usar strpos para buscar una palabra en una cadena hay que poner que no sea falso?

Tags: php

Tuve que buscar una manera para encontrar una palabra dentro de una cadena en php y lo conseguí, pero no entiendo muy bien el por que.
Por ejemplo ¿no seria más facil poner ==true antes que !==false?
y que conseguimos exactamente con que no sea falso?
aqui pongo un ejemplo  de un codigo que funciona perfectamente.

```
$a = 'How are you?';

if (strpos($a, 'are') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: Si lees la documentacion de `strpos` verás que **devuelve un número** indicando el indice de la ocurrencia **si lo encuentra, y falso si no lo encuentra**. Es por eso que no puedes decir `== true' . Recuerda que este sitio no es un buscador avanzado. Has de hacer investigación antes de preguntar y leer la documentacion del metodo es lo priemro que deberias comprobar. Mira [ask] para más info. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que `strpos` retorna el indice del primer caracter donde se encuentra la cadena.  En tu ejemplo no hay ninguna diferencia entre usar `== true` o `!== false` pero en otros casos no es lo mismo.  Por ejemplo `strpos("I love php","I")` retornaria `0`.  En PHP el `0` ademas de su valor int, tambien tiene un valor booleano que es `FALSE`.  Entonces si haces esto : `if(strpos("I love php","I") == true)` te va a retornar `FALSE`,  a pesar de que la sub-cadena `I` se encuentra en la cadena `I love php`.  Esa es la razon por la cual `!== false` es preferible, porque funciona en todos los casos.

Comment: Hola Alan. Gracias por responder pero las preguntas de baja calidad, como esta que no muestra lo investigado, es mejor no responder. un saludo

Comment: He editado mi respuesta para aplacar la ira de los moderadores.

Comment: No hay ira alguna Alan. solo intento que las publicaciones sean de la mayor calidad y rigor posible.